# Attribute "transform" works for some elements, not others Chrome iOS

Tags: javascript, css, ios, google-chrome, svg

first post so apologies if my formatting is rough - I will try to present verbose issue information.
Background info - I need to use Javascript to perform transformations on nested SVG elements.
Platform: Google Chrome iOS

Problem Description:
Parent SVG **hangar** does not transform when the *transform* attribute is added.

```
hangar.setAttribute("transform", "scale(" + scale + ") " + 
"translate(" + translateValues.x + "," + translateValues.y + ") ");
```

Child SVG **towG** does transform when *transform* attribute is added.

```
towG.setAttribute("transform", "scale(" + (100/slider.value)*towScale + ")");
```

This may or may not be relevant but the **transform** is performed on a  tag on the Child SVG.

Thanks in advance,
Derrek

*Edit*
When I log the hangar.getAttribute("transform") the expected value is printed, but the hangar SVG is not transformed.

Comment: `transform` is a valid attribute for outermost `<svg>` elements only since version 2 of the spec. Webkit (which is the rendering engine Chrome has to use under iOS) probably has not implemented that yet. Check if it works in Chrome in another OS. (macOS, Windows, Linux)

Comment: @ccprog All transformations work on Chrome Desktop! While working on this project I've found that SVG children of a parent SVG don't respond to *transform* in the <SVG> tag, only responding to *transform* in a wrapper <g> tag.

Interestingly, the **only** element that isn't transforming is the outermost <SVG> tag serving as a canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing support locally within a CSS file without Javascript. If it doesn't work, then Google Chrome iOS still hasn't implemented support for the transform attribute, unfortunately :(

User agent scans are inefficient, but it's the only way to find out if a mobile user has Chrome for iOS.

I would suggest using a CSS media query, and then scan if X element is displayed, then that means that the display is of your specified size, and if it returns true then you start the scan. You have to find the user agent string and search for 'Chrome iOS' somewhere in there.

Edit: I installed the User Agent Manager extension on my browser, and the user agent string I got from it was this: `Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 13_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/80.0.3987.95 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1`. Hope it helps

If it is on Chrome iOS, then you'd want to replace that property with something similar, so as to maintain compatibility, partial compatibility is better than none.

In the meantime, you would probably want to submit a report to Google on this issue, as Chrome iOS is a pretty big userbase, you don't want to have to keep making these exceptions.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of setting the attribute `transform`, try setting the `transform` within the `style`:

```js
hangar.style.transform = "scale(" + scale + ") " + "translate(" + translateValues.x + "px," + translateValues.y + "px) ";

towG.style.transform = "scale(" + (100/slider.value)*towScale + ")";
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Potato!
Setting the transformation using .style.transform results in a null value when I inspect the "transform" attribute, whereas the way I am currently doing it I see the expected value but the transformation isn't performed.

Comment: transform as style and transform as attribute have conflicting syntax. CSS `translate()` must use units and there must be whitespace between parameters. CSS `scale()` has a different center of transformation (center of bounding box) than the attribute (origin of user space coordinate system).